# Remove row when within group we reach a treshold in pandas

Tags: pandas

Hel lo I need help with pandas.

Here is the table :

```
Col1 Col2 
Grp1 80.3
Grp1 129.2
Grp1 356.0
Grp1 435.3
Grp2 20.2
Grp2 34.0
Grp2 67.0
Grp3 130.3
Grp3 167.9
```

And the idea is to remove row when within each Grp, the number in col2 is already > 100.
Here I should get :

```
Col1 Col2 
Grp1 80.3
Grp1 129.2
Grp2 20.2
Grp2 34.0
Grp2 67.0
Grp3 130.3
```

Does someone have na idea using pandas, I guess we should use groupby ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
Yourdf=df[df.Col2.gt(100).groupby(df.Col1).cumsum()<=1].copy()
   Col1   Col2
0  Grp1   80.3
1  Grp1  129.2
4  Grp2   20.2
5  Grp2   34.0
6  Grp2   67.0
7  Grp3  130.3
```

Comment: thnk you for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do with `groupby`:

```
s = df['Col2'].gt(100).groupby(df['Col1']).transform('idxmax')

df[df.index <= s]
```

Output:

```
   Col1   Col2
0  Grp1   80.3
1  Grp1  129.2
4  Grp2   20.2
7  Grp3  130.3
```

Comment: Kindly check your output